# Use pull to refresh with Text coming instead of refresh icon and navigate to new screen instead of any Future or delay

Tags: flutter, dart, pull-to-refresh

[text](https://drive.google.com/file/d/18TeaJExWOxrdbxJDKIPsjDMmOqxtrcQS/view?usp=share_link)

I want to have such behaviour, when user pulls down he get a Text pull to add more and the widgets on current screen to drag down along with it.
To pull down show Text and navigate on release.

```
body: Column(
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                      flex: 4,
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [
                          const Text('Spent This Week',
                              style: kSmallDarkGreyTextStyle),
                          Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            textBaseline: TextBaseline.ideographic,
                            children: [
                              const Padding(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.all(3),
                                child: Text('₹', style: kBigDarkGreyTextStyle),
                              ),
                              Text(
                                weekAverage.toStringAsFixed(2),
                                style: kBlackAmountTextStyle,
                              )
                            ],
                          )
                        ],
                      )),
                  Expanded(
                    flex: 5,
                    child: Column(
                      children: const [
                        Text(''),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
```

I did not use RefreshIndicator as it does not allow me to change the refreshing icon, I want text in place of it. I searched for different ways to achieve it ended up with.

[link](https://medium.com/flutter-community/how-to-create-your-own-pull-to-refresh-custom-refresh-indicator-widget-in-flutter-a3aa4e8bb42d)

tried to use it changed all column items from the expanded widget to use widgets with a particular height

```
import 'package:expense_manager/constants.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:custom_refresh_indicator/custom_refresh_indicator.dart';
import 'package:responsive_sizer/responsive_sizer.dart';
import 'AddExpenditureScreen.dart';

class CurrentWeekScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static String id = 'current_week_screen';

  @override
  State<CurrentWeekScreen> createState() => _CurrentWeekScreenState();
}

class _CurrentWeekScreenState extends State<CurrentWeekScreen> {
  late double weekAverage = 23454.99;
  IndicatorController controller = IndicatorController();
  onlyDecimal(double weekAverage) {}
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          elevation: 0,
          leading: const Icon(
            Icons.search,
            color: Colors.black,
            size: 28,
          ),
          actions: [
            IconButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              icon: const Icon(
                Icons.add_circle_outlined,
                color: Colors.black,
                size: 28,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        body: CustomRefreshIndicator(
          
          builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child, IndicatorController controller) { return Text('Pull to refresh'); },
          onRefresh: () async{ 
            Navigator.pushNamed(context, AddExpenditureScreen.id);
          },
          child: ListView(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            children: [
              SizedBox(
                height: 38.h,
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    const Text('Spent This Week', style: kSmallDarkGreyTextStyle),
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      textBaseline: TextBaseline.ideographic,
                      children: [
                        const Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(3),
                          child: Text('₹', style: kBigDarkGreyTextStyle),
                        ),
                        Text(
                          weekAverage.toStringAsFixed(2),
                          style: kBlackAmountTextStyle,
                        )
                      ],
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 60.h,
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                  children: const [
                    Text(''),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
    );
  }
}
```

Was able to navigate

Comment: kindly show ur RefreshIndicators code

Comment: @JBJason did the changes you asked for

Answer (score 0):

Used [**custom_refresh_indicator**](https://pub.dev/packages/custom_refresh_indicator) for the purpose,

[Go through this article](https://medium.com/flutter-community/how-to-create-your-own-pull-to-refresh-custom-refresh-indicator-widget-in-flutter-a3aa4e8bb42d)

Important things to note is the functioning of **AnimatedBuilder** and **Transform**

[the results](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ete2mFsmGelBAXHpcQMP2UkY9nHDkLom/view?usp=share_link)

In the screen you want this call the indicator and specify onAction and provide a **ListView** as a child

```
        body:AddMoreIndicator(
            onAction: () async {
              await Future<void>.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 1000));
              Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => AddExpenditureScreen(
                            loggedInUser: loggedInUser,
                          )));
            },
            child: ListView(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              children: [ .... ]
            ),
        )
```

Create a swipe_action.dart file =>

```
import 'package:custom_refresh_indicator/custom_refresh_indicator.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '../constants.dart';

const kPullToRefreshContentColor = Color(0xff877162);

class AddMoreIndicator extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget child;
  final VoidCallback onAction;

  const AddMoreIndicator({
    Key? key,
    required this.child,
    required this.onAction,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    const height = 100.0;
    return CustomRefreshIndicator(
      onRefresh: () async => onAction(), //i need to animate to new screen
      trigger: IndicatorTrigger.leadingEdge, // i need leading edge
      child: child,
      builder: (
        BuildContext context,
        Widget child,
        IndicatorController controller,
      ) {
        return AnimatedBuilder(
            animation: controller,
            builder: (context, _) {
              final dy = controller.value.clamp(0.0, 1.25) *
                  -(height - (height * 0.25));
              return Stack(
                children: [
                  Transform.translate(
                    offset: Offset(0.0, -dy),
                    child: child,
                  ),
                  Positioned(
                    top: -height,
                    left: 0,
                    right: 0,
                    height: height,
                    child: Container(
                      color: const Color(0x783453FF),
                      transform: Matrix4.translationValues(0.0, -dy, 0.0),
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 30.0),
                      constraints: const BoxConstraints.expand(),
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                        children: [
                          if (controller.isLoading)
                            Container(
                              margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0),
                              width: 16,
                              height: 16,
                              child: const CircularProgressIndicator(
                                color: kPullToRefreshContentColor,
                                strokeWidth: 2,
                              ),
                            )
                          else
                            const Icon(
                              Icons.arrow_downward_rounded,
                              color: kPullToRefreshContentColor,
                            ),
                          Text(
                            getText(controller),
                            style: const TextStyle(
                              color: kPullToRefreshContentColor,
                            ),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              );
            });
      },
    );
  }

  String getText(IndicatorController controller) {
    if (controller.isDragging || controller.isCanceling) {
      return "Pull to Add expense";
    } else {
      return "Adding...";
    }
  }
}
```